# Sonar runner issue for c and cpp together

Tags: c++, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have a project with c and cpp files together (based on Visual C++ project), tried to use the sonar with the sonar.properties files with out setting the language and setting the excluded plugins as

sonar.excludePlugins=csharp,css,delphi,flex,javascript,php,plsql,python,ruby,vb,vbnet,web,xml

Now the sonar indexes all the c and cpp files, but it gives parser error complaining headers are not found and giving the NCLOC (total lines of code) as 0 or 1.

Is there any other properties that needs to be set to support c and cpp together ?

Comment: Which C/C++ plugin are you using? The commercial or the community one?

Comment: using the commercial one

Comment: SonarSource Support will be happy to help you sort through this, then.

Comment: ok will reach support